# How to change space between caret and text inside input?

Tags: css, caret, letter-spacing

Letter spacing given -0.02rem by design, that's why space between caret and letter is too small in input. Is there any way to solve this problem without changing letter-spacing in css?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2wXm.png)

```
input, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: var(--text);
    padding: 10px 12px;
    caret-color: #00a2ed;
    letter-spacing: -0.02rem;
    border: 2px solid var(--text);
    background-color: var(--articleBg);
}
```

Comment: As far as i know you cannot style the caret ( except color ) . You could make a custom input ( eg  using a `div`  ) and do everything with javaScript. But that would be a pain for such a small inconvenience. Also, please share code in your questions that reproduce your problem, not images.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added my code to my question

Comment: Given you have basically no spacing between characters what would you want to happen if the caret was in amongst text rather than at the end. Would you want subsequent characters to shift along a bit to give more space (temporarily)?